# WARNING ** : bad d-i Packages file (time distortion or clock problem)

Tags: linux, debian, apt, gpg, debian-installer

I install a linux archive via an old NAS in flash kernel boot, and after struggling with the packages, apt fires me on that:

```bsh
Jan 1 01:08:26 main-menu[209] : INFO : The menu item 'download-installer' is selected
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: gpgv : 
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: Signature made on Sat Apr 25 11:01:30 2015 UTC using RSA key ID 473041FA
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: gpgv: 
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: key 473041FA was created 1282936517 seconds in the future (time distortion or clock problem)
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: gpgv : 
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: WRONG signature of "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: 
Jan 1 01:08:26 net-retriever: error: Bad signature on /tmp/net-retriever-2952-Release.
Jan 1 01:08:32 anna [2948] : WARNING ** : bad d-i Packages file
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: gpgv : 
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: Signature made on Sat Apr 25 11:01:30 2015 UTC using RSA key ID 473041FA
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: gpgv: 
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: key 473041FA was created 1282936511 seconds in the future (time distortion or clock problem)
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: gpgv : 
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: WRONG signature of "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: 
Jan 1 01:08:32 net-retriever: error: Bad signature on /tmp/net-retriever-2973-Release.
Jan 1 01:08:35 anna [2948] : WARNING ** : bad d-i Packages file
Jan 1 01:08:35 main-menu[209]: INFO: The menu item 'download-installer' succeeded but asked to be left unconfigured.
```

Any idea ? knowing that ntp/date/timedatectl doesn't exist obviously

Source tuto : https://github.com/Dees7/openstora/blob/master/pages/How_to_install_Debian_Linux_on_NETGEAR_Stora.md

Step #Running the installer

Comment: You may have to go in through the existing OS on the NAS to set the clock. Or check the support site for Netgear for a way to do it from ssh/serial. You may even need to restore the base image for the NAS.  Bottom line you need to boot to some OS so you can set the time.  Then start this process over from the start.  Also, this kind of hack, you can often get more knowledgeable answers from the community.

Comment: Unfortunately I do this because there is no support Netgear, and it concerns a product that does not boot without access to their servers that no longer exist, so impossible to start or reinstall any OS, forced to flash a custom ROM to my great regret.

Comment: You really don't have `date`?  That should be in `coreutils`.

Comment: Yes, don't have date, timedatectl, hwclock... it's a debian-installer access